# windows command line get files modified on the last x minutes

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to grab files from a windows folder and copy them into another folder based on the last modified date and time.

Is there a way to compare date times in a batch file?

BY this I mean to get minute hour day month year of last file modification and compare it to the current system minute hour day month year?

Answer (score 0):

For starters I am doing

```
@Echo Off

For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydateDD=%%a&& set mydateMM=%%b&& set mydateYY=%%c)
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytimeHH=%%a&& set mytimeMM=%%b)
echo _%mydateDD%_
echo _%mydateMM%_
echo _%mydateYY%_
echo _%mytimeHH%_
echo _%mytimeMM%_
echo %date%=date
echo %time%=time
```

The result is quite close but I get a not cool space in the year part:

*30*
_01_
_2013 _
*21*
_47_
30-01-2013=date
21:47:35,93=time

Answer (score -1):

Well and why not using xcopy... geee

```
xcopy c:\test_CMD\COLLECT c:\test_CMD\EXTRACT /D:%mm%-%dd%-%yyyy% /M

Syntax
      XCOPY source [destination] [options]

Key
   source      : Pathname for the file(s) to be copied.

   destination : Pathname for the new file(s).

   [options] can be any combination of the following:

Source Options

   /A           Copy files with the archive attribute set (default=Y)

   /M           Copy files with the archive attribute set and
                turn off the archive attribute, use this option
                when making regular Backups (default=Y)

   /H           Copy hidden and system files and folders (default=N)

   /D:mm-dd-yyyy
                Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
                If no date is given, copy only files whose
                source date/time is newer than the destination time.

   /U           Copy only files that already exist in destination.

   /S           Copy folders and subfolders

   /E           Copy folders and subfolders, including Empty folders.
                   May be used to modify /T.

   /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...

               The files can each contain one or more full or partial
               pathnames to be excluded.
               When any of these match any part of the absolute path of
               a SOURCE file, then that file will be excluded.
               For example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
               all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
               .obj extension respectively.

Copy Options

   /W           Prompt you to press a key before starting to copy.
   /P           Prompt before creating each file.

   /Y           Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file.
                may be preset in the COPYCMD env variable.
   /-Y          Prompt to confirm overwriting a file.

   /V           Verify that the new files were written correctly.
   /C           Continue copying even if an error occurs.

   /I           If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
                e.g. when the destination does not exist.

   /Z           Copy files in restartable mode. If the copy is interrupted part
                way through, it will restart if possible. (use on slow networks)

   /Q           Do not display file names while copying.
   /F           Display full source and destination file names while copying.
   /L           List only - Display files that would be copied.

Destination Options

   /R           Overwrite read-only files.

   /T           Create folder structure, but do not copy files. Do not
                include empty folders or subfolders. 
                /T /E will include empty folders and subfolders.

   /K           Copy attributes. XCOPY will otherwise reset read-only attributes.

   /N           If at all possible, use only a short filename (8.3) when creating
                a destination file. This may be necessary when copying between disks
                that are formatted differently e.g NTFS and VFAT, or when archiving 
                data to an ISO9660 CDROM.

   /O           Copy file Ownership and ACL information.

   /X           Copy file audit settings (implies /O).
XCOPY will accept UNC pathnames
```

> never reinvent the wheel :p

Comment: and this how to add the current date as parameter @echo off
setlocal
set "dd=%date:~0,2%"
set "mm=%date:~3,2%"
set "yyyy=%date:~-4%"